# How to add subcategories to the blogroll?

Tags: plugins, pages, archives, links, blogroll

I'm looking for a way to create subcategories in my blogroll...

For example:

```
Downloads
-> Windows
-> Mac
-> Linux
```

I want to create a real **page** (not a widget) where the main categories and beneath the sub categories are listed...

Is there any way?

Comment: Please, add new information directly into the Question, not in the Comments... You can edit and improve the Q as new Answers or Comments pop up. :::: Probably you don't need a plugin, only a template page and consulting the Codex: [`wp_list_bookmarks`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_bookmarks).

Comment: I've edited the Q, as plugin recommendation is [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq). What you need is a [`Template Page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) and the function `wp_list_bookmarks`. If you can, try to build something with the info in those documents and bring up any doubts you have...

Answer (score 0):

The wordpress links section doesn't allow for subcategories. You could, however, create a custom "menu" (in the Appearance section of the dashboard) and then display that menu using a sidebar widget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think my question is a bit misunderstood... I want to create a real **page** (not a widget) where the main categories and beneath the sub categories are listed...

Comment: That's relatively easy then: create the page ans then use the wp_nav_menu option to display the menu on the page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu -- you will either need to add this code into the page template or use a plugin that allows you to use PHP code in your page contents.